# How to make indesign file from programming

Tags: php, c++, adobe-indesign

I ask if there is any way to make new in-design file ( .indd) 
from programming ! 
the problem is that i want to make a program for newspaper to manage the newspaper dynamic content and then convert the html5 ( or any other output ) into in-design with its columns and pages

Comment: Did you do any research on the Indesign file format? What standard does it follow? Is it open source? Likely it's not possible.

Comment: i doing research from 2 days , i found only xml way , and it not make what i want . please let me know , why all this negative votes ! . every one can help us or ignore us , instead of this negative votes , that will cause blocking my account

Comment: @Mostafa: if you can make your research clear in your questions, that does help. If you can edit in a programming attempt, together with the problem you are having with it, it will probably be re-opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [IDML file format specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/IDML/idml-specification.pdf) (pdf).

> IDML is an XML representation of an InDesign document or components. This document describes the structure of IDML files, the XML schema for IDML validation, and provides examples of IDML file content. This document has been updated for IDML version 7.0, which corresponds to InDesign CS5. Sections that are new in this version are indicated by the notation “(IDML 7.0).”

You can also use some [SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html) from Adobe

Comment: thanx for ur positive help

Comment: IDML and INDD are two different formats. IDML is publicly specified in https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/IDML/idml-specification.pdf , INDD doesn't seem to have a public spec.